# how to access redux store from react component for authentication

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, redux, components

I'm maintaining a react redux app and trying to get authentication to one of the routes in the app, namely `/dashboard` . I want to pass in a boolean state from redux store to a prop named `authed` but struggling... As currently, I just pass in `true` value as a fake value.

```
 import React from 'react'
 import {
  HashRouter,
  Route,
  Link,
  Switch,
  Redirect
  } from 'react-router-dom'

// components that are main pages
import Home from './containers/Home'
import Login from './containers/Login'
import Signup from './containers/Signup'
import NotFound from './containers/NotFound'
import Dashboard from './containers/Dashboard'
import IntersectionForm from './containers/IntersectionForm'
import IntersectionDetail from './containers/IntersectionDetail'

import { connect } from 'react-redux'

const PrivateRoute = ({component: Component, authed, ...rest}) => {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) => authed === true
        ? <Component {...props} />
        : <Redirect to={{pathname: '/', state: {from: props.location}}}/>}
    />
  )
}

function mapStateToProps (state) {
  return state
}

const PrivateRouteContainer = connect(mapStateToProps)(PrivateRoute)

const Routes = (history) => {
  return (
    <HashRouter history={history}>
      <switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Login}/>
        <Route exact path="/signup" component={Signup}/>
        <PrivateRouteContainer authed={true} path='/dashboard' component={Dashboard}/>
      </switch>
    </HashRouter>
  )
}

export default Routes
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function mapStateToProps (state) {
  return state
}
```

by doing this your component will receive props with all your states across reducers.

for example, if you have:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import todos from './todos'
import counter from './counter'

export default combineReducers({
  todos,
  counter
})
```

Then your `PrivateRoute` will get `todos` and `counter` props.

That's why its better if your `mapStateToProps` grabs just the prop it needs.

```
function mapStateToProps (state) {
  return {
     authed: state.nameOfReducer.isAuthed, // or whetever is the value you need to know if user is authorized
  }
}
```

If you, however, don't `combineReducers` and you have just one reducer in your app then:

```
function mapStateToProps (state) {
  return {
     authed: state.isAuthed,
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Make a call to your auth end-point (POST) in auth_actions from your componentDidMount function.
- dispatch an action once you get the response within actioncreator.
- in authReducer  - for example: isAuthenticated:true/false and return the payload.
- access that value by making your react component connected and within
  mapStatetoprops of the component and you can access this boolean
  value - using this.props.authValue.